# Microsoft Bot framework assembly references

Tags: c#, botframework

I have the following code but from the Microsoft bot creation tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-quickstart

When I copy and paste it my using statements don't seem to be being used when they should be in the example? I've tried adding the using statements it suggest but I don't think that is required. I have errors on `[BotAuthentication]` and `Activity` "Type or namespace name 'Activity' could not be found' etc

I have the nugget packages installed as well.

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using Microsoft.Bot.Connector;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.CognitiveServices.QnAMaker;
using System.Web.Services.Description;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.PersonalityChat;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.PersonalityChat.Core;

namespace BenTestBot
{
    [BotAuthentication]
public class MessagesController : ApiController
{
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
    {
        if (activity.GetActivityType() == ActivityTypes.Message)
        {

            //await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new Qna_Rich_Cards.Dialogs.QnaDialog().DefaultIfException());
            await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new Dialogs.BasicPersonalityChatBotDialog().DefaultIfException());

        }
        else
        {
            await HandleSystemMessageAsync(activity);
        }
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        return response;
    }
```

Comment: Are you by chance using visual studio for mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have already installed the nuget packages then this should not be there.
Maybe you should check the version of the packages and try updating the packages.

For [BotAuthentication] and activity to work you need Microsoft.Bot.Connector; that is already there in your case so just try updating.

Comment: I was in a preview version rather than a stable version, thank you!